# Python style: use imported class as namespace for related custom data?

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

I was wondering if it's ok to use an imported, 3rd-party class as a namespace for you related custom variables? Say, the following code:

```
import pycurl

curlm = pycurl.CurlMulti()
curlm.pool = [pycurl.Curl() for i in range(POOL_SIZE)]
curlm.running = set()
```

In this example, pycurl.CurlMulti is some 3rd-party class and *pool* and *running* are my variables (not provided by CurlMulti), but intended to be used together with curlm.

Comment: As you can see there's nothing to stop you from doing so, however, you may inadvertently overwrite something that module is depending on and cause things to break (or worse - misbehave without breaking)... So I would say *don't do so*

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. What you want is a [WeakKeyDictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakKeyDictionary). You can associate arbitrary values with arbitrary objects without worrying about different modules overwriting each other's variables or the dict keeping objects alive too long.

Suppose you write a module `foo.py` that sets `thing.whatever = 5`. Two Python versions later, `thing` offers a `whatever` method. Everything breaks, and you didn't even touch your code.

Suppose you write a module `foo.py` that sets `thing.whatever = 5`. Two months later, you're working on a different project, and you write a module `bar.py` that sets `thing.whatever = 4` on the same `thing`. Horrible breakage occurs due to unrelated decisions you made months ago.

Comment: The first concern: Overwrite a subclass's member by adding a new member in the base class. The second concern: redefine a member variable in two separate translation modules. The third concern: overwrite a function in the current namespace by using an import *. Personally I don't think these are pitfalls that catch out an OO oriented programmer.

Comment: Wait... he wasn't talking about module-level constants. Rewriting this!